# Angular.js: ng-repeat based on item in object

Tags: angularjs

Basically have two ng-repeats on the page that share an Object. I want to repeat items only if they match the `type` data.

Mock Object

```
        $scope.events = [
            {
                date: "1/16/13",
                time: "11:30",
                type: "First",
                restaurant: "Quiznos",
                location: "Echo",
                cuisine: "American",
                link: "http://google.com/event?id=239292"
            },
            {
                date: "1/16/13",
                time: "1:30",
                type: "Second",
                restaurant: "Snarfs",
                location: "5th Floor",
                cuisine: "American",
                link: "http://google.com"
            }
];
```

Markup

```
        <tr ng-repeat="event in events.type " onClick="window.open('{{event.link}}','_blank');">
                <td>{{event.time}}</td>
                <td>{{event.restaurant}}</td>                   
                <td>{{event.location}}</td>
                <td>{{event.cuisine}}</td>
        </tr>
```

So I want two ng-repeats. on for type = First, and one for type = Second

Something like `ng-repeat="event in events.type = 'First'"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You're looking for [the filter filter](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3afilter)...

```
<tr ng-repeat="event in events | filter:{ type: 'First'}"/>
```

Comment: This is correct! I was looking at filters from a different perspective, awesome to know. Thanks!

Comment: Just realized you also answered my previous filter/orderBy question, I appreciate your patience while I'm learning haha. :}

Comment: Ha! No problem. I want more people to use Angular, so hopefully I have fewer projects I need to work on with "homebrew" JS "frameworks".